# How to add a custom action to the controller in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add another action to my controller, and I can't figure out how.

I found this on RailsCasts, and on most StackOverflow topics:

```
# routes.rb
resources :items, :collection => {:schedule => :post, :save_scheduling => :put}

# items_controller.rb
  ...
  def schedule
  end

  def save_scheduling
  end

# items index view:
<%= link_to 'Schedule', schedule_item_path(item) %>
```

But it gives me the error:

```
undefined method `schedule_item_path' for #<#<Class:0x6287b50>:0x62730c0>
```

Not sure where I should go from here.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A nicer way to write

```
resources :items, :collection => {:schedule => :post, :save_scheduling => :put}
```

is

```
resources :items do
  collection do
    post :schedule
    put :save_scheduling
  end
end
```

This is going to create URLs like

- `/items/schedule`
- `/items/save_scheduling`

Because you're passing an `item` into your `schedule_...` route method, you likely want `member` routes instead of `collection` routes.

```
resources :items do
  member do
    post :schedule
    put :save_scheduling
  end
end
```

This is going to create URLs like

- `/items/:id/schedule`
- `/items/:id/save_scheduling`

Now a route method `schedule_item_path` accepting an `Item` instance will be available. The final issue is, your `link_to` as it stands is going to generate a `GET` request, not a `POST` request as your route requires. You need to specify this as a `:method` option.

```
link_to("Title here", schedule_item_path(item), method: :post, ...)
```

Recommended Reading:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: This is why I believe OP meant to have `member` collections, as outlined in my answer.

Comment: To get the link_to working I had to do this: `<%= link_to 'Schedule', schedule_item_path(item), method: :post %>`  Notice the `method: :post` is outside the `schedule_item_path()`

Comment: yup, small typo. fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Ref [`Rails Routing from the Outside In`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Following should work

```
resources :items do
  collection do
    post 'schedule'
    put 'save_scheduling'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `routes.rb` like this:

```
match "items/schedule" => "items#schedule", :via => :post, :as => :schedule_item
match "items/save_scheduling" => "items#save_scheduling", :via => :put, :as => :save_scheduling_item
```

And the `link_to` helper can not send `post` verb in Rails 3.

You can see the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: That's overly verbose and will be harder to maintain.

Comment: Are there another way to generate the specific `_path` method?