# Rails 4 / jQuery: Need entry of value in a form input to autofill other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

Using simple_form, I'm trying to get the entry of an id input (`team_id`) to autofill a couple of the other inputs (`team_city` and `team_name`) in a form creating a new `team_game`.  I've gone through every implementation I can find, but to no avail (my most recent reference: [Jquery ajax and controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828909/jquery-ajax-and-controller-method)).  This one is like quicksand for me, the more I struggle with, the farther I get pulled down.  My code is below.  Currently, its throwing the AJAX error in the javascript.  I'm also getting this in the console:

```
Started GET "/team_games/populate_team_city_and_name?team_id=1" for ::1 at 2016-02-12 13:28:50 -0800
Processing by TeamGamesController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"team_id"=>"1", "id"=>"populate_team_city_and_name"}
  TeamGame Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "team_games".* FROM "team_games" WHERE "team_games"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find TeamGame with 'id'=populate_team_city_and_name:
```

So, in addition to my AJAX issue, I appear to be doing something wrong with my routing (used this as a guide: [How to add a custom action to the controller in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763818/how-to-add-a-custom-action-to-the-controller-in-rails-3)).

Using Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.5.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**models/team_game.rb**

```rb
class TeamGame < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :team_city
  attr_accessor :team_name
  attr_accessor :opposing_team_city
  attr_accessor :opposing_team_name

  belongs_to :team, class_name:  'Team',
                    inverse_of:  :team_games

end
```

**models/team.rb**

```rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :team_games, class_name:  'TeamGame',
                        inverse_of:  :team

end
```

**view/team_games/_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @team_game do |f|

  = f.input :team_id,   input_html: { id: 'team-id' }
  = f.input :team_city, input_html: { id: 'team-city' }
  = f.input :team_name, input_html: { id: 'team-name' }
```

**controllers/team_games_controller.rb**

```rb
def populate_team_city_and_name(team_id)

  @team = Team.where(id: team_id)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @team }
  end

end


private

def team_game_params
  params.require(:team_game).
    permit(:team_id,
           :team_city,
           :team_name,
           :is_home_team,
           :opposing_team_id,
           :opposing_team_city,
           :opposing_team_name,
           :stadium_name
           :game_date,
           :game_time)
end
```

**assets/javascripts/team_games.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#team-id').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var teamId = $('#team-id').val();

    request = void 0;
    request = $.ajax({
      url: 'populate_team_city_and_name',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { team_id: teamId }
    });

    request.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        $('#team-city').val(data.city);
        $('#team-name').val(data.name);
      } else {
        $('#team-name').val('There is no team with entered Id');
      }
      console.log("Success!!")
    });

    request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}");
    });

  });
});
```

**config/routes.rb**

```rb
resources :team_games do
  member do
    get :populate_team_city_and_name
  end
end
```

### UPDATE: WORKING

Following are the changes I made to get the autofill to work.  They may not all be necessary, but it works, so that's something.  Thanks to Jeff F. for heading me down the right road.

**view/team_games/_form.html.haml** (revised)

```
= simple_form_for @team_game do |f|

  = f.input :team_id,   input_html: { id: 'team-id' }
  #no-team-with-id-msg There is no team with entered id
  = f.input :team_city, input_html: { id: 'team-city' }
  = f.input :team_name, input_html: { id: 'team-name' }
```

**controllers/team_games_controller.rb** (revised)

```rb
def populate_team_city_and_name

  @team = Team.where(id: params[:team_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @team }
  end

end


private

def team_game_params
  params.require(:team_game).
    permit(:team_id,
           :team_city,
           :team_name,
           :is_home_team,
           :opposing_team_id,
           :opposing_team_city,
           :opposing_team_name,
           :stadium_name
           :game_date,
           :game_time)
end
```

**assets/javascripts/team_games.js** (revised)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#no-team-with-id-msg").hide();

  $('#team-id').change(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var teamId = $('#team-id').val();

    request = void 0;
    request = $.ajax({
      url: '/team_games/populate_team_city_and_name?team_id=' + teamId,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json'
    });

    request.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        $("#no-team-with-id-msg").hide();
        $('#team-city').val(data[0].city);
        $('#team-name').val(data[0].name);
      } else {
        $("#no-team-with-id-msg").show();
        $('#team-city').val('');
        $('#team-name').val('');
      }
    });

    request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}");
    });

  });
});
```

**config/routes.rb** (revised)

```rb
get 'team_games/populate_team_city_and_name',
  to: 'team_games#populate_team_city_and_name',
  as: 'populate_team_city_and_name',
  defaults: { format: 'json' }

resources  :team_games
resources  :teams
```

Part of my routing problem appears to have been that I previously had the 'get' route after the resources routes, which I'm guessing is why the javascript 'GET' was routing to the `team_games#show` action.

I also changed the handling of the message *'There is no team with entered id'* since it seemed inappropriate for it to appear in an input.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the url for that route incorrectly. Try changing your ajax to:

```
request = $.ajax({
  url: 'team_games/' + teamId + '/populate_team_city_and_name',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
@team = Team.where(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jeff!  If I make the change you suggest, firstly I get:

Comment: `Started GET "/team_games/team_games/1/populate_team_city_and_name" for ::1 at 2016-02-12 15:22:48 -0800
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/team_games/team_games/1/populate_team_city_and_name"):`  So, something is still strange with the routing (it's doubling `/team_games` in the URL.)

Comment: If I add a "/" to the beginning, it seems to generate the correct route, but then I get this: `Started GET "/team_games/1/populate_team_city_and_name" for ::1 at 2016-02-12 15:27:44 -0800
Processing by TeamGamesController#populate_team_city_and_name as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1):`  When `teamId` is in the middle, it appears to be passing it as 'id' like it would with show or edit, rather than as 'team_id' to the controller method.

Comment: I made an edit to this, but the answer was a little to far off for an edit, so I put a new answer.  +1 for being on the right track, though.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the answer above a bit, but it was actually a little too far from correct, so I'm answering anew.  Upvoted as it's on the right track, though.

Add a line to your form like:

```
= simple_form_for @team_game do |f|
  = f.input :id, as: hidden, :input_html => { id: 'team-game-id', :value => @team_game.id }
  = f.input :team_id,   input_html: { id: 'team-id' }
  = f.input :team_city, input_html: { id: 'team-city' }
  = f.input :team_name, input_html: { id: 'team-name' }
```

Then in your JS:

```
var teamId = $('#team-id').val();
var teamGameId = $("#team-game-id").val();

{ ... }

request = $.ajax({
  url: '/team_games/' + teamGameId + '/populate_team_city_and_name?team_id=' + teamId,
  type: 'GET'
});
```

The reason for the query parameter is because you can't specify the teamId in the URL unless you make a route that allows you to.  The membership is on the TeamGame model, not the team.  Alternatively, you could specify a route like:

```
get '/team_games/:id/populate_team_city_and_name/:team_id' => 'team_games#populate_team_city_and_name'
```

But as-is, you don't have a matching route.  However, the query parameter will show up in `params`.

Then in your controller:

```
@team = Team.find params[:team_id]
```

You may want to also ensure that this Team not only exists, but also that Team.team_games includes the TeamGame in question.  But I'll leave that exercise to you!

Comment: thanks for the awesome response.  While you were putting it together, I was still pursuing the lead from Jeff above which, as you state, got me on the right track.  I ended up coming up with a solution, different from yours, but perhaps not better.  I would greatly appreciate it if you wouldn't mind taking a look at my edit to the original question and let me know if you see any pitfalls. Thanks!

Comment: It appears mine will work fine when creating a new `team_game`, but I will need to incorporate what you have done to edit an existing one, e.g. your use of a `@team_game.id`, which doesn't exist yet when I'm creating a new `team_game`, but will be necessary when I'm editing it.

Comment: I think it's fine.  My only suggestion would be to move the `/team_games/populate_team_city_and_name` call to the TeamsController using `team#show`.  You should then be able to get JSON if you pass it an accept header looking for `application/json`. But that's me being a stickler and doesn't affect how it works in the end.